# Eclipse > CDT + Cygwin > How to configure a C++ compiler?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, gcc, compiler-construction, eclipse-cdt

So, I've been looking all over.  I can't find anywhere that talks about specifically how to configure Eclipse + CDT to run the gcc / gcc++ compiler.

I am running Eclipse on a windows box, but I've installed Cygwin.

[edit] I've installed Cygwin, and I've added C:\Cygwin\bin to my path environment variable.  I'm now getting this error:

> **** Build of configuration Default for project helloWorld ****
>
> (Cannot run program "make": Launching
>   failed)

I've confirmed that make is indeed not there as the message suggests.  I'm confused that Cygwin installed g++ / gcc without make, but whatever.  I'm installing all the rest of the development section of the available cygwin pkgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the PATH environment variable of windows to where is located gcc and make (C:\cygwin\bin ?). Then you can simply use a makefile to compile your application (or use the makefile generally generated by eclipse).

Answer (score -1):

type in the following in the environment path variables:
c:\cygwin\bin\
that is just put a backslash after bin. 
Now try to run