# objdump ELF and Windows

Tags: visual-studio, gnu, elf, binutils, objdump

I am fairly new to this subject, that is ELF and any Linux related stuff. I am trying to write an ELF file and would prefer to do it on WinXP.

My question is, can this be done with MS Visual Studio including the compilation? As far as my understanding goes, ELF files can not be compiled on Windows OSs. Well, at least that's what my Google research discovered to me. 
Do I have to setup a Linux OS and compile it there?

Can I use the objdumo (part of GNU binutils) to analyze any ELF file on WindowsXP?

Any help and links are very appreciated.

Comment: What OS do you want to run this ELF file on?

Comment: Not certain yet. It's an embedded environment but we did not decide yet.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use the Visual Studio IDE with other tools invoked from custom build steps. **However**, I would not recommend doing it to compile binaries for other platforms that are not Microsoft based.

You could install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (with gcc/g++) to compile ELF binaries and configure [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliosr) to use them. You might find some tips on how to do this [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339755/eclipse-cdt-cygwin-how-to-configure-a-c-compiler).

Comment: gcc/g++ on Cygwin still produce Windows executable file format. It is not ELF binary file format

Comment: @SergeC, you can compile a cross-compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [ELFIO library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfio/). It contains WriteObj and Writer examples. By using the library, you will be able to create ELF binary files on Windows and run them on other OSes that are able to operate it.