# Cannot run C/C++ project on eclipse+cygwin+cdt

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

As we all know, Eclipse can not only run Java project, It also can run C/C++, Python, PHP etc, but we need to install plugins and configure run environment. I want to run C++ Project on Eclipse+cygwin+cdt (Windows 7), I have added following these environment variables.
"C:\cygwin64\usr\include"
"C:\cygwin64\lib"
"C:\cygwin64\bin"

and configure Eclipse toolchain = CygwinGcc and binary parsers = PE Windows Parser, I also set  sth about "Paths and Symbols", but I still cannot run C/C++, following is the error info:

"Lauching CTest Debug" has encounted a problem. The program file specied in the launch configuration does not exist."

there is no binaries files, is there something wrong with it? I'm confused.

Comment: Did you start eclipse from within a cygwin shell? What does it say when the compiler is run?

Comment: This answer might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339755/eclipse-cdt-cygwin-how-to-configure-a-c-compiler

Answer (score 0):

An executable probably doesn't exist in your debug folder.

There is a thread on how to get c++ running on Eclipse here:

[The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690644/the-program-file-specified-in-the-launch-configuration-does-not-exist)

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: Now I can build, but after building, there are no binary files but some .mk file such as subdir.mk, sources.mk,makefile etc. How can I directly generate .exe file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you install gcc toolchain successfully in Cygwin? Try to include gcc, gdb and make when you install cygwin.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I tried that. You may know that comment requires 50 reputation. As you see...

Comment: There's a reason for this! It doesn't mean you should give your comments as "answers".

Comment: OK. You mean anyone can't share his or her opinion just because the  answer is short? There are varieties of ways to make this answer longer and seemingly meaningful. But this does not mean anything. I just want to remind something for him.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely not an `answer`. But I have no way to comment it? Right? I think the potential solution to this problem is the most important thing. Anyway I don't want to debate on this...

Comment: Now I can build, but after building, there are no binary files but some .mk file such as subdir.mk, sources.mk,makefile etc. How can I directly generate .exe file? Thanks